# npm -v throws 471 error cannot find module.js

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

i recently installed `node 6.9.2` on my PC and it is working fine but when i check npm using `npm -v`, i throws a `module.js:471 throw err. cannot find module C:\Users\MyUser\*`.

I already tried re-installing `node` and `git`, setting `environment variable` paths, and removing `node_modules`. I've been searching the internet for a couple of days now but i have no luck. I would really appreciate some help.

thanks in advance.